# Laravel envoy with putty public key

Tags: linux, laravel, putty

I am trying to do a Laravel Envoy task on my linux server. For logging in to the linux server, i am using putty for the public key. When i try to run the envoy task i get this error. It has something to do with the key

[screenshot off the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFrKI.png)

Comment: The `authorized_keys` file isn't a valid key file. You're using the wrong file entirely. The `-i` argument should point at a valid *private* key file that's in the *server's* authorized keys list (as its public key).

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for your help! Do you know what file do i have to point to?

Comment: You'd point it at a private key that is authorized (via its public key) on the server's `authorized_keys` file. Where that is can vary; on Linux/OSX it'd probably be in `~/.ssh`, often `id_rsa`.